# OpenCV: npoints > 0 in function 'drawContours' - create mask using json file

Tags: python, json, opencv

I am trying to create a mask using json file but get an error as

> 'error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /Users/xperience/actions-runner/_work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2502: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'drawContours'

And print out only one dot. What should I change on my code?

Json file looks like this:

```
[[[1866, 905], [1823, 905], [1819, 909], [1804, 913], [1796, 917],
[1776, 921], [1772, 924], [1756, 932], [1749, 932], [1745, 936], ....]]]
```

Here is my code:

```
x_val = []
y_val = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[i])):        
        #if data[i][j] != {}:
        shape1_x=data[i][j][0]
        shape1_y=data[i][j][1]
        x_val.append(shape1_x)
        y_val.append(shape1_y)

fig = plt.figure()

plt.imshow(img.astype(np.uint8)) 
plt.scatter(x_val,y_val,zorder=2,color='red', marker = '.', s= 55, alpha= 0.25)

ab=np.stack((x_val, y_val))

img2=cv2.drawContours(img, [ab], -1, (255, 255, 255), 1)

mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]))
img3=cv2.drawContours(mask, [ab], -1, 255, -1)
```

[Output image with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76D7J.jpg)

Comment: [mre] is required.

Comment: Don't really understand how you're iterating... `data[i][j]` is just a single point, which isn't a contour of course.

Comment: @August Thank you! I got better image now but still get same error message. Is contour still the problem?

Comment: Nevermind! I edit the code as ab=np.stack((x_val, y_val), axis=1) and there is no error! Thank you!